# How to resolve entry point not found error in xampp?

Tags: xampp

I installed xampp in my pc and it was showing an error of missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll file. After fixing this error, still Apache is not starting, now it's displaying the below error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoGYI.png)
Help in fixing this error.

Comment: Please give us more information on what OS version, when this error occurs (does xampp start up or does this occur when app is running), and some error logs

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and xampp version 3.2.2. Its properly but to start Apache it's failing, it's only starting MySQL

Comment: Could be a number of issues its hard to say. Apache may be getting blocked. Are you running as administrator? Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling? Does apache run as a standalone installation?